# python windos disk monitor(snmp) ，How the two scripts merged into a script?

Tags: python, snmp

I must use to proactively monitor, I need to be monitored to the windos of the entire hard drive, the drive letter the way through the transfer of parameters.If I achieve what I want, you need these three scripts.Who can help me improve the next?
I want a script to complete the work of the two scripts. How to merge?

1:code  Cdisk

```
import sys
import os
import commands
warning = sys.argv[2]
critical = sys.argv[3]
ip =sys.argv[5]
#val = sys.argv[1]
StorageAllocationUnitsC="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.4.1"#last4.1=Cdisk,4.2=Ddisk....
StorageSizeC="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.5.1"#last5.1=Cdisk,5.2=Ddisk....
StorageUsedC="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.6.1"#last6.1=Cdisk,5.2=Ddisk....

StorageAll = "snmpwalk -v 2c -c public %s %s" % (ip,StorageAllocationUnitsC)
(r_c,r_e) = commands.getstatusoutput(StorageAll)
if r_c != 0:
    print "C - snmpwalk is Error."
else:
    StorageAllC = r_e.split("INTEGER: ")[-1][:4]

StorageSize = "snmpwalk -v 2c -c public %s %s" % (ip,StorageSizeC)
(r_c,r_e) = commands.getstatusoutput(StorageSize)
if r_c != 0:
     print "C - snmpwalk is Error."
else:
     StorageSize = r_e.split("INTEGER: ")[1]

StorageUsed = "snmpwalk -v 2c -c public %s %s" % (ip,StorageUsedC)
(r_c,r_e) = commands.getstatusoutput(StorageUsed)
if r_c !=0:
    print "C - snmpwalk is not value."
else:
    StorageUsed =  r_e.split("INTEGER: ")[1]



diskall = int(StorageAllC)*int(StorageSize)/1024/1024/1024
diskusd = int(StorageAllC)*int(StorageUsed)/1024/1024/1024
diskrate = round(float(diskusd)/float(diskall)*100,2)

if int(sys.argv[2]) > int(diskrate):
    print "Critical - pls check Cdiskrate %s" % diskrate + "%"
    ret = 2
elif int (sys.argv[3]) > int(diskrate):
    print "Warning - pls check Cdiskrate %s" % diskrate + "%"
    ret = 1
else:
    print "OK - good! %s" % diskrate + "%"
    ret =0
sys.exit(ret)
```

2:code  Ddisk

```
import sys
import os
import commands
warning = sys.argv[2]
critical = sys.argv[3]
ip =sys.argv[5]
#val = sys.argv[1]
StorageAllocationUnitsC="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.4.2"#last4.1=Cdisk,4.2=Ddisk....
StorageSizeC="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.5.2"#last5.1=Cdisk,5.2=Ddisk....
StorageUsedC="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.6.2"#last6.1=Cdisk,5.2=Ddisk....

StorageAll = "snmpwalk -v 2c -c public %s %s" % (ip,StorageAllocationUnitsC)
(r_c,r_e) = commands.getstatusoutput(StorageAll)
if r_c != 0:
    print "C - snmpwalk is Error."
else:
    StorageAllC = r_e.split("INTEGER: ")[-1][:4]

StorageSize = "snmpwalk -v 2c -c public %s %s" % (ip,StorageSizeC)
(r_c,r_e) = commands.getstatusoutput(StorageSize)
if r_c != 0:
     print "C - snmpwalk is Error."
else:
     StorageSize = r_e.split("INTEGER: ")[1]

StorageUsed = "snmpwalk -v 2c -c public %s %s" % (ip,StorageUsedC)
(r_c,r_e) = commands.getstatusoutput(StorageUsed)
if r_c !=0:
    print "C - snmpwalk is not value."
else:
    StorageUsed =  r_e.split("INTEGER: ")[1]



diskall = int(StorageAllC)*int(StorageSize)/1024/1024/1024
diskusd = int(StorageAllC)*int(StorageUsed)/1024/1024/1024
diskrate = round(float(diskusd)/float(diskall)*100,2)

if int(sys.argv[2]) > int(diskrate):
    print "Critical - pls check Cdiskrate %s" % diskrate + "%"
    ret = 2
elif int (sys.argv[3]) > int(diskrate):
    print "Warning - pls check Cdiskrate %s" % diskrate + "%"
    ret = 1
else:
    print "OK - good! %s" % diskrate + "%"
    ret =0
sys.exit(ret)
```

Comment: Do you have a programming problem?

Comment: If you want someone to review your code, you can try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I want a script to complete the work of the two scripts. How to merge?

Comment: How the two scripts merged into a script?

Comment: I can achieve a single monitor disk, but no idea of ​​these two scripts merged into a script.Way to pass parameters to monitor disk C, D,.

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is combine some variables.  There are better ways of building snmp queries, but that's out of scope for this question.

```
import sys
import os
import commands

warning = sys.argv[2]
critical = sys.argv[3]
ip =sys.argv[5]
#val = sys.argv[1]

StorageAllocationUnitsC ="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.4.1"
StorageAllocationUnitsD ="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.4.2"
StorageSizeC="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.5.1"
StorageSizeD="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.5.2"
StorageUsedC="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.6.1"
StorageUsedD="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.6.2"

results = dict()

for oid,descr in [(StorageAllocationUnitsC,"C_StorageUnits"), 
    (StorageAllocationUnitsD,"D_StorageUnits")]:
    StorageAll = "snmpwalk -v 2c -c public %s %s" % (ip,oid)
    (r_c,r_e) = commands.getstatusoutput(StorageAll)
    if r_c != 0:
        print "%s - snmpwalk is Error." % descr
    else:
        results[descr] = r_e.split("INTEGER: ")[-1][:4]

for oid,descr in [(StorageSizeC, "C_StorageSize"), 
    (StorageSizeD, "D_StorageSize"), (StorageUsedC, "C_StorageUsed"), 
    (StorageUsedD, "D_StorageUsed")]:
    Storage = "snmpwalk -v 2c -c public %s %s" % (ip,oid)
    (r_c,r_e) = commands.getstatusoutput(Storage)
    if r_c != 0:
         print "%s - snmpwalk is Error." % descr
    else:
         results[descr] = r_e.split("INTEGER: ")[1]
```

All results are stored in the python dictionary called `results`

Comment: dt={'C': 1, 'D': 2, 'E': 3 , 'F':4}

StorageAllocationUnitsC="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.4.%s" % dt.get(val)
StorageSizeC="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.5.%s" % dt.get(val)
StorageUsedC="1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.6.%s" % dt.get(val)